# Plotly stacked bar chart in subplot -- visually differentiate the "stacked" values inside the subplot

Tags: plotly, subplot, plotly-express, stacked-bar-chart, plotly.graph-objects

Assume we're using the plotly px.data.iris() dataset to generate a stacked bar chart. This is pretty straight-forward using plotly express:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()

df = df[["sepal_width", "sepal_length", "species"]]
df = df[(df["sepal_width"] > 2.7) & (df["sepal_width"] < 3.3)]
df
```

```
        sepal_width sepal_length    species
    0   3.5         5.1             setosa
    1   3.0         4.9             setosa
    2   3.2         4.7             setosa
    3   3.1         4.6             setosa
    4   3.6         5.0             setosa
  ...
  141   3.1         6.9             virginica
  143   3.2         6.8             virginica
  145   3.0         6.7             virginica
  147   3.0         6.5             virginica
  149   3.0         5.9             virginica
```

The bar chart should be "stacked", using the species column:

```
fig = px.bar(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species")

fig.show()
```

And will look something like this:
[image: Plotly Express Stacked Bar Chart]

My problem is that I need to include this as a subplot, with several other subplots:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

bigFig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    specs = [
        [{"type": "pie"}, {"type": "pie"}],
        [{"type": "bar"}, {"type": "bar"}],
    ],
    subplot_titles=("pie1", "pie2", "bar1", "bar2")
)
```

I can't (or, can't figure out how to) use a plotly express bar chart in the subplot, and I can't figure out how to translate the stacked part -- `color="species"` -- into a graph_objects chart in such a way to make the plot **look* as pretty as the plotly express version, and visually differentiate the species values.

My attempt at a "go" bar chart is:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

bar_trace = go.Figure(go.Bar(
     x=df['sepal_width'], y=df['sepal_length'] # how to indicate the base/color selector
)

bigFig.add_trace(bar_trace, row=2, col=2)
```

This results in a bar chart that looks something like:
[image: Plotly graph_objects bar chart]

It will appear in the desired subplot of `bigFig`. While it is stacking the `sepal_length` values (good), I need for the stacking to be "based" on the Species values, and be visually apparent.

When I tried to declare the base:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=df["sepal_width"], y=df["sepal_length"], base=df["species"]))
fig.update_layout(barmode="stack")
fig.show()
```

The result doesn't match the expected output, and the apparent stacks are all the same color:

[image: Plotly Graph_Object Bar Chart, with "base"]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77395009/stacked-bars-in-subplots-with-plotly) solution and grabbed the `barmode="stack"` idea from it. But, it did not help my situation and I can't figure out why.

So, please help me get the pretty version into a subplot. I must be missing something fundamental, but I've been banging my head on this for a while. TIA!

Comment: Since plotly.express also has a built-in subplotting function, the following code can be used to subplot by seed. Also, where is the code for the pie chart? And what is the xy axis with 2 rows and 2 columns? `px.bar(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", facet_col='species', color="species")`

Comment: My subplots will contain pie charts and bar plots. That will prevent me from using the facet_col approach. 

I'm going to try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56727843/how-can-i-create-subplots-with-plotly-express